# Оптимизация многопоточного кода

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Требуется периодически и независимо друг от друга менять параметры view-элементов (текст на кнопках). Для этой цели использовал `Timer` и `TimerTask`. Все работает. Но я создал много объектов `Timer` и `TimerTask`: на каждую кнопку (10 штук). Запускаются таймеры для каждой кнопки одновременно. Как я понимаю, создается 10 отдельных потоков и это не есть хорошо? Нужно ли как-то в данном случае оптимизировать архитектуру программы, например, использовать `ExecutorService` для создания пула или что-то еще? Или моя реализация оптимальна?

И еще вопрос: как использовать `ExecutorService` вместе с `Timer` и `TimerTask`? Нигде не нашел примеров их совместного использования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование `ExecutorService` сможет вам помочь только в том случае, если вы иногда останавливаете (убиваете) поток, а затем какой-то запускаете. Если это так, то неактивные потоки будут переиспользованы при попытке запустить новый `TimerTask` в `ExecutorService`.

В том случае, если у вас количество запущенных TimerTask статично (допустим, на форме `n` кнопок, на каждой висит `TimerTask`, количество кнопок по ходу программы не изменяется), тогда использование `ExecutorService` вам ничем не поможет.

И не забивайте вызывать `shutdown()` или `shutdownNow()` когда заканчиваете работу с `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Да. Я периодический останавливаю какой-то поток, затем когда-то возобновляю его. 
Тогда следующий вопрос: как использовать `ExecutorService` вместе с `Timer` и `TimerTask`? Нигде не нашел примеров их совместного использования.

Comment: @Doraemon Знаете, я после вашего вопроса сам заинтересовался, можно ли что-то придумать в вашей ситуации с `ExecutorService` и пришёл к тому выводу, что использование `Timer` - самое оптимальное.  `ExecutorService` в вашем контексте не вписывается, так как класс `Timer` просто выбрасывается, а без него все бенефиты использования `TimerTask` сводятся к нулю. Используйте `Timer` и не усложняйте себе жизнь микрооптимизациями). Если я вам помог - можно пометить вопрос решённым. Иначе - задавайте вопросы, с удовольствием отвечу)

Answer (score 1):

Для данной задачи если вы протестировали и вас все устраивает, не вижу смысла переделывать. `ExecutorService` в данном случае лучших результатов не даст. Да вы создаете 10 потоков, но все они спят пока таймер не сработает, так что это не есть проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Я подобные задачи решал немножко по другому. На все про все нужен один таймер, который будет срабатывать каждую секунду или (каждую десятую секунды, по обстоятельствам). Также нужен счетчик срабатываний. Теперь при каждом срабатывании таймера, увеличиваем счетчик на единицу. Следующим куском кода будет один switch (или группа if, по обстоятельствам), где будет решаться, что делать.

Как следствие, один таймер - легче управлять. А вот для десятка таймеров нужно обычно держать массив.
Также, в случае множества таймеров, отладка может превратиться в кошмар.
И ещё, в некоторых случаях, нельзя гарантировать порядок срабатывания таймеров. А это может сильно рушить логику.

Comment: Да, хорошее решение, у меня в проектах оно тоже встречается, но не всегда можно хорошо эту практику внедрить, иногда это просто технически невозможно.